# How do I map a set of string objects using JPA Annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class TestClass implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private Set<String> mySet;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<String> getMySet() {
        return mySet;
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: TestClass.mySet[java.lang.String]
```

or if I leave off the @OneToMany

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: test_class, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(my_sets)`]

Comment: Hibernate's @CollectionOfElements annotation solved the problem for me. It's hibernate specific, but I don't plan on swapping out my JPA implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find a pretty decent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa).  The rules for Lists apply to Sets too.

Answer (score 6):

Ooh oh, I had to do this one.

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = String.class)
```

Comment: This is also what I had to do, but it is hibernate specific. In my situation that's fine with me.

Comment: @ElementCollection in JPA2, this answer is the better approach. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa