# Persist collection fields with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Using hibernate, how can I persist a class with a `List<String>` field?

Consider the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Blog {
    private Long id;
    private List<String> list;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public List<String> getList() { return list; }
    public void setList(List<String> list) { this.list = list; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to save it, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Blog, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(list)]
```

I tried adding '`@CollectionOfElements`' to `getList()`, but then only the `id` is saved to the library.  No corresponding column is created for the list.

Note: I'm just trying Hibernate, so I could use documentation links that we will help me understand the collection relationship management in Hibernate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa). Maybe it is of help.

Did you apply @CollectionOfElements as follows?

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements(
targetElement = java.lang.String.class
```

)

Comment: Thanks!  New table is created to save the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Hibernate Annotations Documentation about Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections) basically you have to tell the list in what relation it stands to.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="blog")
public List<String> getList() { return list; }
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I would get thw following error: '@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on uk.co.pookey.hibernate.model.Blog.list references an unknown entity: java.util.List

Comment: That should work though. Did you import the Hibernate or the JPA annotation?

Comment: Imported JPA javax.persistence annotation

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Serializable` object seems to work better.  Changing `list` property to `ArrayList<String>` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 package com.company.directDataLoader.model.admin;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<Collection<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ";";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Collection<String> stringList) {
        return stringList != null ? String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList) : "";
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return string != null ? Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR)) : emptyList();
    }
}
```

In the entity class:

```
@Column(name="table_keys")
@Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
private Collection<String> tableKeys;
```