# persist collection as string in hibernate

Tags: string, hibernate, collections

I am using hibernate as a persistence layer.I want to persist collection of string in hibernate.I want to concat element of collection and then save to table.how can i do this with annotation?(dose getter and setter change?)

Comment: A relevant code example would certainly help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persist collection fields with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360606/persist-collection-fields-with-hibernate)