# Unable to map a hashmap using JPA annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hashmap

I am using dropwizard which internally uses JPA annotatons and hibernate to map  objects. One of the object has a map field which I have defined as

```
    @Column
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    Map<String, String> routes;
```

I keep seeing the following error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table
```

I have tried a number of things mentioned on SO

Added the @`MapKey` annotation
Added annotations on getters
changed Map to HashMap nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: where do you want to persist this Map? into a column? into a (join) table? into a column serialised? And what is the "targetClass" trying to do ? you have generics defined on the field so targetClass is irrelevant

Comment: yes as a column of the table serialized

Comment: in which case you could either try `@Lob`, or alternatively use an `@AttributeConverter` like on this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_map_converter_simple_simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use @MapKeyColumn(name="column_name"). This link might be useful: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_.28JPA_2.0.29

Comment: same result after adding the @MapKeyColumn annotation

Comment: Did you try below code with Map<String, String> routes = new HashMap<String,String>(); Also using @MapKeyColumn. Check this similar question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324839/java-hibernate-mapping-exception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-map

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa