# Hibernate Exception: Trying to map a Collection OneToMany without JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map an entity the contains a Collection without use JoinTable.
The exception that I keep having is:
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: Foo.collection[java.lang.String]

I know that it works with JoinTable, but then I get 2 tables while I want only one table. I know that if it worked then I'd have the "name" many times in the table (one for each element in the collection).

I looked in the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association see section: 2.2.5.3.1.2. Unidirectional and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)and many examples but yet I cant find what I'm doing wrong :(
I also found many questions on this issue where the common answer is to use JoinTable, but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

I tries playing with it, like using @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName="NAME") but no good..

I'm using Java6, jpa2, hibernate 3.5.4. and MySql

Any advice?
Thanks in advance,
Baba

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T1")
public class Foo {

private long id;

    private String name;

    protected Collection<String> collection;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

    @Column(name = "COLLECTION")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
public Collection<String> getCollection() {
    return collection;
}

    /*
     * setters...
     */
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to persist a property of type List<String>in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa)

Comment: it doesnt look like a duplicate to me-or I just dont get it...

Comment: According to the answer there, changing `@OneToMany` to `@CollectionOfElements` should fix the problem. Is that not the case?

Comment: no, cause using that creates an additional table and what I was is to have only one table.
and by the way, CollectionOfElements is deprecated so in that case it would be to use ElementCollection.

Comment: How can you have your base entity and a collection in a single table?!

Comment: this is what I'm trying to figure out. I think its possible cause if when using ElementCollection I get 2 tables, where in the second one the rows are pairs of entity name and an element from the collection, then why not fuse these 2 tables to one? its only an additional column for an unique id and a column for the "name" (i take into account that the "name" will appear more than necessary when usint 2 tables).
So my question is whether it is possible and how to do that. cause from what I understand from the documentation i looks ppossible.

Comment: @babasmith: This doesn't make sense to me. Can you post your table definitions?

Comment: @ruakh: i dont have definitions, i let hibernate/jpa to create the table. but i guess it'd look like a fusion of both the tables that are created when using "ElememtCollection", but with only one ID and the "NAME" attribute appearing many times. i agree that this isnt the best practice for this, but i really need all that in one table.

Comment: You need unique key on each row - how will you solve this if only collection column value will change ( for each element of collection ) ?

Comment: @smoula22: how about indexing the table? i guess its possible to have a unique identifier to each row - using an id that is defined in the table and not in the entity (to be used only as unique id).
cause anyway each row in the table will be unique since the combination of entity_id and the element from the collection (one in a row) is a unique combination.

Comment: i think you can do it but not using hibernate, 
something like (indexId, entryId, String elOfColumn[0]), (indexId, entryId, String elOfColumn[1]) a then retrieve as collection using select elString on entryId - but the point is that you cannot do it through hibernate configuration

Comment: @smoula22: thank you, i almost gave up on this thread. i'm now researching to see if theres some provider that allows that.

Answer (score 2):

This is in Hibernate docs.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
@Column(name="nickname")
public Set<String> getNicknames() { ... }
```

Comment: this isnt the case. your solution creates 2 tables while i'm trying to do that with only one table (as i wrote in the question). thanks anyway :)

Comment: How can you store base entity and the collection in one table?

Comment: it is possible in the DB, I've seen it (in an Oracle table). I'm just trying to do that with hibernate in order to computerize the whole process. thats my question.