# Google App Engine/JPA: Strange behaviour using Embeddable class

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I have an `Embaddable` class with a `List<String>` whose modifications are not being save unless I modify another field too. Please take a look at this to understand:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableClass {

    private Integer someField;

    @Basic
    private List<String> someList;

    public EmbeddableClass() {}

    public Integer getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }
    public void setSomeField(Integer someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public List<String> getSomeList() {
        return someList;
    }
    public void setSomeList(List<String> someList) {
        this.someList = someList;
    }
}
```

If I don't modify the `Integer someField`, any modifications on `someList` won't be persisted.

This is the code I use to test:

```
        // ... lookup entity user...

        log.severe("some list size before changing: " + user.getMainTeam().getEc().getSomeList().size());

        //user.getMainTeam().getEc().setSomeField(new Random().nextInt()); // <- PROBLEM HERE!
        user.getMainTeam().getEc().getSomeList().add("darn");

        // ...  persist entity user...
```

That line with `setSomeField` is necessary, otherwise the "size before changing" will be `0` the second time I run the test for a given user.

And finally, this is how the Embeddable class is defined in its owner (class `Team`):

```
    @Embedded
    private EmbeddableClass ec;

    public EmbeddableClass getEc() {
        return ec;
    }

    public void setEc(EmbeddableClass ec) {
        this.ec = ec;
    }
```

I'm using GAE SDK 1.7.0.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa resolve your problem?

Comment: No, I cannot use JPA 2.0 (no time to upgrade & test everything), the OP is not using GAE and I'm not getting any exceptions.

Comment: Try marking your collection as dirty, I am not sure about GAE or Datanucleus, but JDOHelper has this feature.

Comment: @JMelnik Thank you very much! `JDOHelper.makeDirty(user.getMainTeam(), "ec");` makes it works! Still, this is a bug, isn't it? If so, I'd like someone to answer this question with this fiding, otherwise I can accept an answer of you with this information.

Comment: Whther it's a bug or not isn't of much interest since, as you say, you're not using a recent version (and you got a workaround anyway). In fact you're using an ancient version (early 2009). The point it becomes a bug is if you use the current version(s) and find a problem, demonstrate it with a testcase, and report it to Google in their issue tracker; that's how they would like to know about such things.

Comment: @DataNucleus Sorry, what you mean? I'm using GAE SDK 1.7.0 from Jun 22 2012. Do you mean SDK 1.7.0 uses an ancient version of DataNucleus API?

Comment: You're using which GAE JPA version? you said "i cannot use JPA 2.0", in which case you're using GAE JPA v 1.0.10, which is ancient, as said on other questions

Comment: I thought JPA 2 was only available on GAE SDK 1.7.1, released 2 days ago. Is this wrong?

Comment: Totally wrong, its been one of Google's "optional downloads" for 9 months.

Comment: Well, so it was not stable. Please, tell me: this recent GAE SDK version 1.7.0 points to an old DataNucleus API? I'm asking this because now I'm having another problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096928/gae-jpa-datanucleus-strange-exception-while-trying-to-persist-entity-illegalar) and I think it is related to problems found on old DataNucleus versions.

Comment: All GAE JDO/JPA "releases" are 'stable' by definition (that's what TDD is for - in this case v2.x releases are more 'stable' than the v1.0.x releases since they pass more tests). To answer your question, obviously you are using an old DataNucleus API ... look at your jars datanucleus-core-1.1.x. The current release is datanucleus-core-3.1.0!

Comment: This is from Google Dev Blog, 3 days ago: "We’re excited to announce that with the latest upgrade we’re making V2 of the DataNucleus plugin fully supported" - people are afraid to use things before they read messages like this. I must have read about the optional download but wasn't confident to change. I'm trying to upgrade now, and as far as I understood, I must use ANT and practically lose all benefits from the eclipse plugin. Am I missing something? Thank you for your help so far, you've always helped me.