# GAE/JPA/DataNucleus: Strange exception while trying to persist entity (IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1)

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I'm getting an exception after I added this embedded field in my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Team extends DataObject
{
    @Embedded
    private TeamEvolution teamEvolution = new TeamEvolution();

    // NEW FIELD:
    @Embedded
    // @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "buffer", column = @Column) })
    // @Enumerated
    private ScoutBuffer scoutBuffer;
 ...
```

This guy is very simple:

```
@Embeddable
public class ScoutBuffer 
{
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 150;

    @Basic
    private List<String> buffer;
   ... // from here on there are only methods...
```

When I try to merge my modifications I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1
    at com.olympya.futweb.datamodel.model.ScoutBuffer.jdoProvideField(ScoutBuffer.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.provideField(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2585)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.provideField(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2555)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.postUpdate(CollectionMapping.java:185)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.EmbeddedPCMapping.postUpdate(EmbeddedPCMapping.java:133)
    // etc, etc...
```

I don't think there's anything to do, but I had to use `JDOHelper.makeDirty` before merging the entity for it to perceive that I modified `scoutBuffer`:

```
   team.getScoutBuffer().add(playerIds);
   JDOHelper.makeDirty(team, "scoutBuffer");
   em.merge(team);
```

As you can see commented in the code, I tried the workaround described [here](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=55), without success. Strange thing is that is from 2009... I'm using GAE 1.7.0, by the way. Also, I tried cleaning/re-enhancing the datamodel.

Comment: So if its from 2009, why not use something more recent?

Comment: @NeilStockton The link points to a post from 2009, but I'm using a recent version from GAE, that's what's strange.