# play2 - saving list of strings to model won't stick

Tags: java, list, playframework-2.0, persistence

In my (java) Controller in a Play2 project I'm saving some data to an object. 
So `entity` here is an instance of a `Model` subclass.

I do stuff like this

```
log.debug("Saving title=" + title + ", tags=" + tags);
entity.title = title;
entity.tags = tags;
entity.save();
// verify:
ModelClass m = ModelClass.find.byId(entity.id);
log.debug("Saved title=" + m.title + ", tags=" + m.tags);
```

Where `title` is a `String` and `tags` is a `List<String>`. The debug log says

```
Saving title=foo, tags=[bar, quux]
Saved title=foo, tags=null
```

So data is coming in, I'm not getting any warnings, but the list of strings is just lost somewhere along the way. I'm just using an in-memory h2 db, maybe it works when I'm really persisting it, but... what's up with this?

Edit: The generated SQL create syntax doesn't contain "tags" at all. So there's obviously something wrong with that.

Edit: see [How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa)

Comment: seems something is wrong with your entity.save()

Comment: Well, I don't _have_ a save() implementation, it's just using the `play.db.ebean.Model.save()` method.

Answer (score 1):

In JPA you must declare a List as [@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) for it to be persisted. It seems that EBean do not support this feature.

One way to do it should be to declare your List tags as [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) (ie. not persisted) and have methods to manage it while keeping up to date a simple String that contains your tags comma separated. That would be this String that gets persisted in a single column.