# map a Object filed to a table by jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have a `entity Class` with a field. the value of field may will be a `String` or a `List<String>`, so my reference type is `Object`.

```
class entity{
    private Object field;
}
```

I want to map this `Class` to a `Table` by `JPA`. How should I use `JPA`?  By contract I know the field can be either `String` or `List<String>` and I want to save values in a column not in a separate table like using ElementCollection.My DB is oracle.

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa)

Comment: You should redesign your model so that you have type safety, rather than having to check WTF is stored there at some time of the day. Barring that you look at an `AttributeConverter` so that it converts it into a String for storing in the datastore (and put up with the crap model design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not map an object.

In your case you have a String or a list of strings. My advice is to map one of them and follow with your desition.

The easy way is to map the string with an specific delimitation: string1; string2; string3; ....; and do a split of the string to get all the strings you have.

String[] strings = string.split(";");

This way if you only have one element then you know is a String, if not you have a list.

Other solution is to create a table with id:value and create the proper jpa maping with @OneToMany or @ElementCollection:

```
javax.persistence.ElementCollection

@ElementCollection
Map<Key, Value> strings;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

Hope this helps.