# Spring data jpa persisting large List<String> property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the right way to persist a huge `List<String>` entity property with Spring jpa (`postgresql` db)? I've been converting it to `byte[]` which was stored as `bytea` in db , however it causes different formatting troubles (even simply rewriting the list).
`List<String>` can be as big as 10.000.000 entities. sometimes i just need to take the list, change a few elements and write it back.

As i understand, other options are:

1. use `ElementCollection` - which i think isn't the solution for such large lists.
2. Store it as large string with split characters - guess that isn't very efficient option either.

currently i use these methods to transform the list to/from `byte[]`:

```
    public static List<String> bytesToStringListByInputStream(byte[] bytes) {
        List<String> lines;

        if (bytes == null) {
            return lines;
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bais);
        try {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                lines.add(in.readUTF());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }


    public static byte[] arrayListToByteArray(List<String> list){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        for (String element : list) {
            try {
                out.writeUTF(element + System.lineSeparator());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

**entity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class UserFile implements Serializable {
    ...some fields...

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private byte[] fileData;
```

however in different cases after changing the list and persisting it, random characters appear in ouput lines - sometimes numbers or special symbols.
I guess i can find find a reason why it happenning, but in any case - is this a right way to persist a large lists (through `byte[]` jpa entity field and `bytea` postgresql field)?

Comment: Is it not simply possible to bind as a List<String>, or if that isn't directly supported, a String[] ?  The postgres JDBC driver should allow the latter, if not the former...

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/arrays.html

If hibernate attempts to do setObject or setArray with a String array into the postgres jdbc driver, in theory, it should work....

Comment: I'm confused by this question. This seems like you are using the DB like a file. Why not store each list item as a row in the DB? Wouldn't it be more efficient to search for the couple elements to modify if they were indexed? There are strategies to store large numbers of rows in a DB.

Comment: because there are multiple users each having multiple (10+) large files. Does creating a table for each such list makes sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa)

Comment: @crizzis yeah i did refer to the solutions described in that topic. I think they might not be suitable for multiple very large lists.