# save List<String> by jpa without create new table

Tags: jpa

Class definition

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_domain")
public class Domain(){
 @Id
 String id;
 String fieldA;
 String fieldB;
 String fieldC;
 List<String> operations;
}
```

Table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE `t_domain`  (
  `id` varchar(38) ,
 `fieldA` varchar(255) ,
 `fieldB` varchar(255) ,
 `fieldC` varchar(255) ,
  `operations` varchar(255) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

JSON

```
{"id":"1",
"fieldA":"a",
"fieldB":"b",
"fieldC":"c",
"operations":["a","b"]}
```

From this page['https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection'],said `The ElementCollection values are always stored in a separate table.`.

In jpa 2.0,`@ElementCollection` is a way to save collection,but it seen to need a new table to store collection value.

Question:
I dont want to create any new table like `domain_operation` or `another_table_name` defind in `@CollectionTable(name="another_table_name")`.

I want to save the json to mysql in only one row.

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11

Answer (score 0):

**Ignore the below, it refers to original version of the question**

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="t_domain",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
@Column(name="operations")
```

Without specifying table name, Hibernate uses `entityName_collectionName`, which in your case gives `domain_operation`

Comment: It is not work ,hibernate said ` Unknown column 'Domain_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Add joinColumn and Column annotations to specify column names (See updated answer)

Comment: Still unwork, said Duplicate entry '00e7744d-44cd-4164-bb48-4a93738cd460' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Now, the problem lies in the schema, not in the mapping. `t_domain` has primary key `id`, but you want multiple elements in the collection, don't you?

Comment: I update the question description. Can you understand the description? I need some feedback to know did I  describe the problem in  correct or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa#50448142    
I want the result like this but I dont want to use AttributeConverter

Comment: Yep, now I see it as a different problem. Does the `@Convert` you linked solve your problem? Alternatively, tou could mark your List field as @Transient, map the db column to a String, and use @PrePersist and @PostLoad to fill in the list. I still think a @Convert is much cleaner, any particular reason not to use it?

Comment: `@Convert` make me save the data correctly. But if i want to filtering results by content of that field , it can not work . So that I want to know is any better way for now

Comment: If you are lucky, your db supports json column type. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/ and https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using manually a serializator?

```
String operations;

@Transient
private ObjectMapper mapper;

public void setOperationsList(List<String> in) throws JsonProcessingException {
    operations = mapper.writeValueAsString(in);
}

public List<String> getOperationsList() throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(operations, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
}
```

}