# How to create insert statements for table with Collection

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I have a Spring boot JPA project that has an entity Entitya. This entity has a collection attribute

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>(10);
```

with get/set

I see tables created  - Entitya and Entitya_options [looks like entitya doesnt know anything about Entitya_options. But entitya_options has foreign key to Entitya]
I don't need the extra table, but it's ok

I want to insert data using import.sql, how can I do?

```
Insert into "ENTITYA" (FORMULA,NOTE,ACTION_ID) values (....);
```

How to insert Entitya_options too , when inserting Entitya ?

**EDIT**

Question:
Should I use the below annotations? as mentioned  - [How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa)

```
@ElementCollection // 1
    @CollectionTable(name = "my_list", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")) // 2
    @Column(name = "list") // 3
    private List<String> list;
```

I need **complete** insert statements, that can be put in import.sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import.sql` (Hibernate support) or `data.sql` (Spring JDBC support) files to load data.

Ff you use `JPA` and an `embedded datasource`, your `schema.sql` won’t be taken into effect, because Hibernate’s DDL generation has priority over it.

A solution to that problem is to set the following property:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

Since Spring boot 2, the schema is only initialized by default for embedded datasources. To allow loading data for all types of datasources, you have to set the following property:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:my_script1.sql, classpath:my_script2.sql
```

## Update

```java
@Component
public class MyEntityInitializer implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
EntityaRepository entityaRepository;

@Override
  public void run(String... args) {
   Entitya entitya = new Entitya();
   entitya.setOptions(Arrays.asList("op1","op2"));
   entityaRepository.save(entitya);
 }

}
```

By this you can your entries inserted every time your application is started.
Make sure to check for already existing records, otherwise you get primary key exception.

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking for this, I already have all of this. I am looking for Insert statements with column names and values

Comment: You should look for sql "INSERT INTO SELECT" statements for this. OR  configure a `CommandLineRunner` or `@postConstruct` for performing insert operations on entities

Comment: Please give complete answer. partial comments are not helpful

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I am looking for import.sql option, to keep things clean. I can do insert entitya(..); insert entittya_options(... refering to auto generated id of entitya), but I want be 100% sure that options are pointing to the right entitya. I will insert 1000s of entitya and  times x 4 or 6 options