# How to create a List of String field in Object Model class in java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, list, model

I am creating a Client class where one of the fields is array of String,How can I initialize it in the client model?

```
public class Client{
    @Id
        private String clientId;
        @NotBlank(message = "Client Name cannot be Blank")
        private String clientName;
        private String clientSecret;
        @NotBlank(message = "APIs Granted cannot be blank")
        private List<String> marks; // I am doing like this but gives an error.
        @NotBlank(message = "Status cannot be Blank")
        private String status;
        private String time;
}
```

The marks field is a list of string but its giving a error.Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a `List<String>` like this:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Hello1", "Hello2");
```

Comment: but I dont have to initalize any values as its an entity class

Comment: @HimanshuRanjan Hmm so I didn't understand your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I am creating an entity class where one of the fields is a list,How do I present that List inside the class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa does it help you?