# Spring jpa Entity field List<String> to postgre array filed not working

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have an Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Cat {
  @Id
  private String catId;
  private String catName;
  private List<String> favFoods;
}
```

When I start my Spring boot, it shows this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List
```

I drop the table Cat in DB before starting the app
My yml setting is:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/localtest
    username: catuser
    password:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
```

If I comment out the field of List, everything works fine.
Is there any annotation that I need to add to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code snippet

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "my_list", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
        "id"))
    @Column(name = "list")
    List<String> favFoods;
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Hibernate [how to map the list](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/) by annotating you class with `@TypeDef(name = "list-array",typeClass = ListArrayType.class)` and annotating the list with `@Type(type = "list-array")` i.e.:

```
@Entity
@Data
@TypeDef(
    name = "list-array",
    typeClass = ListArrayType.class
)
public class Cat {
  @Id
  private String catId;

  private String catName;

  @Type(type = "list-array")
  private List<String> favFoods;
}
```