How to map Postgres VARCHAR[][] to String[][] via Spring JPA
I've created a table
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  text_arr VARCHAR[][] NOT NULL
)

and an entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String[][] text_arr;
}

also a repository
public interface TestTableRepository implements JpaRepository<TestTable, String> {}

This configuration doesn't work. I also tried by example from this post https://vladmihalcea.com/multidimensional-array-jpa-hibernate/
like this
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable {
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Type(
      value = StringArrayType.class,
      parameters = @Parameter(
              name = "sql_array_type",
              value = "varchar"
      )
)
@Column(name = "text_arr", columnDefinition = "varchar[][]")
  private String[][] text_arr;
}

my service is able to start, but when I execute
repository.save(entity)

it fails with
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: incorrect binary data format in bind parameter 1
  Where: unnamed portal parameter $1] [insert into test_table (text_arr,id) values (?,?)]; SQL [insert into test_table (text_arr,id) values (?,?)]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: incorrect binary data format in bind parameter 1
        Where: unnamed portal parameter $1

I'm using Spring Boot 3.3.3

Is it really possible, the attached link documents about enum array, not String array, for that I think you should follow - how to convert List to String with delimiter or String array to String with delimiter, one suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448142/10531665

Hibernate supports List serialization to VARCHAR[]. It also supports Enum[][] serialization. I guess, String[][] it should support as well, without workarounds.

After some investigation, I figured out that the problem was not in the configuration but in Postgres. Regarding the documentation
Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension. 

So if you have an array like
new String[][] {{"str1"}, {"str2", "str3"}}

it will fail. As the solution, I stored an array as jsonb.
FYI here is an example of a valid mapping https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/984465ec3af4b564ee321c39567400f54fef321f/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/array/MultiDimensionalStringArrayTypeTest.java#L116
